# JBoss EAP 7 management console custom login page

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

Anyway I can custom Jboss EAP 7 management console login page by adding Log-on Warning Banner in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAL is protected by digest authentication. And as such the browser takes care of the login. Bottom line you won't be able to customize the login.

Answer (score 0):

HAL is the project behind the web console in WildFly: https://hal.github.io/
You can customize it there with extensions (i don't really know the details)